# React Header calculation

Tags: css, reactjs

I've a page with a header component and below it content component. (the containing div doesn't have 100% height)

I want to open a map from top (below the header) to the bottom of the screen. (using all of the space)  **without flex**, in the content component.

One way I thought about : get the height of header (lets say X) **in the content component**.  and I will create a div with top: X, left: 0, right: 0 , bottom : 0   (I saw Airbnb were also doing it)

so I wanted to ask, how do I get the Header height in the content component?  and do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use display:table if flex is unwanted :

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  display:table;
}
.row {
  display:table-row;
  height:100%;
}
header.row {
  background:green;
  height:0;
}
main.row {
  position:relative;
}
main.row div.inner {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue
}
/* test height : 100% */
b {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background:gray;
  margin-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<header class="row">
  <div> here comes header stuff <br/>of any height
  </div>
</header>
<main class="row">
  <div class="inner">
    <b> test to cover height</b>
  </div>
</main>
```